# Is this from an actual episode of Star Trek: The Next Generation?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, episode-identification

[image: Troi making a weird face, label reads "ermagherd the berg"]

Is this an actual, unaltered (aside from the text!) screenshot from a *ST:TNG* episode (or movie)?

What is the explanation for Troi's face?

Comment: @JohnO I've been cranking through the seasons recently, and can definitely say the episode you mention isn't in Seasons 1-4.  Matter of fact, I'm up to Season 5 now and still haven't seen Troi put on a proper uniform as far as I can recall.

Comment: @Iszi I thought Troi put on a uniform in Best of Both Worlds?  I recall a visiting captain making Troi stop wearing her usual outfit.

Comment: @Keen Memory Alpha's article on [Deanna Troi](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Deanna_Troi#Miscellaneous_information) suggests the episode you're referring to may be [Chain of Command](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Chain_of_Command,_Part_I_%28episode%29), which is Season 6, Episode 10.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

It's from ["Timescape" (Season 6 Episode 25)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timescape_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation)).  The main plot of the episode involves the Enterprise and a Romulan ship being stuck in a temporal causality whatchamacallit.

Troi is doing an impression of someone from a Starfleet conference.  The frame capture in question has her in the midst of an exaggerated wink.

[image: Troi mocks a Starfleet representative]

> "Hello, Dianne, I understand you're an empath. I'm a very..."
>
> -*WINK*-
>
> "...sensitive man myself. I'm doing a thesis on inter-species mating rituals. Would you care to join me in some, empirical research?"

For even more fun, if anyone has seen [The Picard Song](https://youtu.be/6rYhRqf757I?t=1m2s) the section that goes:

> *"He just kept talking in one long incredibly unbroken sentence moving from topic to topic so that no one had a chance to interrupt it was really quite hypnotic."*

is from the same scene in the episode.

Comment: Here's a [YouTube link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gD3J7PelvKQ) to the scene. You're welcome. *wink*

Comment: Wow.  I half expected to hear that it was photoshopped.  Now that's acting!

Comment: @Beofett I personally wasn't expecting to find that the scene was anything so far from the norm.  There are many frames of videos which otherwise depict normal human events and interactions, where people appear to be making some very odd faces.

Comment: Data: "Did you help with that research, counselor?" :-)

Comment: The video seems to have disappeared, but here's [another one](http://youtu.be/73sgRKrbRas?t=12s) with the same scene.